# Alsa - record output but don't play to speaker

Tags: linux, alsa

I'm testing out web radio with darkice/icecast, and I have a working setup with a server and client. However, whatever audio the server serves has to be played by the server, and I can't mute it without silencing the radio stream.

How can I still record the audio I'm playing, without it coming out of my server's speaker?

Edit:
Darkice, which is (as far as I understand) the source client, is turning an alsa capture device (found using `arecord -l`) into an audio stream which is passed to icecast.

The issue is that whenever I mute my speakers, so that sound playback is silenced, no sound is captured by darkice. I can't figure out how to have my speakers muted but still have sound playback recorded by darkice, and I've already tried every volume slider in alsamixer.

Comment: Can you add to your question the audio configuration. By the server, do you mean the host running `icecast`? Please update the question, do not answer as a comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.